# What's the meaning of 'pink and gold with youth'?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

Context:

> So has Arthur Less, once pink and gold with youth, faded like the sofa he sits on.

What's the meaning of 'pink and gold with youth'?

Comment: to be x with something. hot and bothered with rage. sweating and panting with effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As young men often do, he probably had pink skin (especially cheeks) in his youth, and golden (blond) hair; now he is not young and his skin is pale or yellow with age and his hair is grey or white. He has faded. So has the old sofa.